# Use purrr::map to apply multiple arguments to a function

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, magrittr, purrr

I have a data frame like this

```
   df <- data.frame(tiny = rep(letters[1:3], 20), 
                  block = rnorm(60), tray = runif(60, min=0.4, max=2),
                  indent = sample(0.5:2.0, 60, replace = TRUE))
```

I nested this data frame

```
nm <- df%>%
       group_by(tiny)%>%
       nest()
```

then wrote these functions

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

model <- function(dfr, x, y){
             lm(y~x, data = dfr)
         }

model1 <- function(dfr){
           lm(block~tray, data = dfr)
          }
```

I want to run this model for all tiny classes, so I did

```
 nm%>%
   mutate(
     mod = data %>% map(model1)
   )
```

the above code works fine but if I want to supply the variables as arguments like I have in the `model1` function, I get errors. This is what I do

```
 nm%>%
    mutate(mod = data %>% map(model(x=tray, y=block)))
```

I keep getting the error
`Error in mode(x = tray, y = block) : unused argument (y = block)`.

Also I tried plotting these using `ggplot2`

```
plot <- function(dfr, i){
    dfr %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x=tray, y=block))+
geom_point()+
xlab("Soil Properties")+ylab("Slope Coefficient")+
ggtitle(nm$tiny[i])

nm%>%
 mutate(put = data %>% map(plot))
```

the idea is that I want `ggplot` to put titles *a*, *b*, and *c* for each of the plots that will be produced. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: doesn't look like `model1()` is defined to take any parameters

Comment: @PierreLafortune, It didn't work. I got the error `Error: is.data.frame(.data) || is.list(.data) || is.environment(.data) is not TRUE`

Comment: one day you kids will stop trying to pipe everything

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use base function `split` to split data into  list of groups.

```
library( purrr )
library( ggplot2 )
df %>% 
  split( .$tiny) %>%
  map(~ lm( block ~ tray, data = .))

df %>% 
  split( .$tiny) %>%
  map(~ ggplot( data = ., aes( x = tray, y = block ) ) +
        geom_point( ) +
        xlab("Soil Properties") + 
        ylab("Slope Coefficient") +
        ggtitle( as.character( unique(.$tiny) ) ) )
```

**Using Functions:**

```
lm_model <- function( data ) 
{
  return( lm( block ~ tray, data = data ) )
}

plot_fun <- function( data )
{
  p <- ggplot( data = data, aes( x = tray, y = block ) ) +
    geom_point( ) +
    xlab("Soil Properties") + 
    ylab("Slope Coefficient") +
    ggtitle( as.character( unique(data$tiny) ) )

  return( p )
}

df %>% 
  split( .$tiny) %>%
  map(~ lm_model( data = . ) )

df %>% 
  split( .$tiny) %>%
  map(~ plot_fun( data = . ) )
```

**Creating formula inside function**

```
lm_model <- function( data, x, y ) 
{
  form <- reformulate( y, x )

  return( lm( formula = form, data = data ) )
}

df %>% 
  split( .$tiny) %>%
  map(~ lm_model( data = ., x = 'tray', y = 'block' ) )
```

Your solution would have worked if you had your function formulated like below.

```
model <- function(dfr, x, y){
  lm( formula = eval(parse(text = paste('as.formula( ', y, ' ~ ', x, ')', sep = ''))),
      data = dfr)
}
```

Comment: this works like the model example I gave in my question. I get to learn another way of doing it which is awesome. however, I want to be able to use a function and supply any arguments I want to the function in the using `map`.

Comment: You did answer part of it. In your `lm_model` function, can I change `block` and `tray` and supply them as arguments in the function? How do I do it?

Comment: Yes. so in this case, I would be passing the Data frame, the `x` variable and the `y` variables to the `lm_model` function and evaluate using the `map` function

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. I don't get why  `df%>%group_by(tiny)%>%mutate(mod = data %>%map(lm_model(x='tray', y='block', data=.)))` doesn't work.

Comment: inside the `lm_model` function, in the second line, put `print(form)`. You will see the magic. For more info, please read `?reformulate`

Comment: see at the end, I added modifications to your function described in the question. Hope this helps

Comment: use `mutate` so it adds the model output as a column to the existing df and that would answer my question. Good job though.

Comment: I would love that

Comment: it is better to keep it as a list, so you can get summary and other statistics

Comment: If you want to attach it to your data frame, in `R` that kind of operation is called parameterization of data frame. Essentially you wil be creating pframes. Instead of attaching the output, attach the functions you created, so you can call the functions on your data to get output whenever needed.

Comment: but this out of scope of this question

Comment: Which of these solutions are you referring to
`df%>%group_by(tiny)%>%mutate(mod = data%>%map(model(x='tray', y='block', dfr=.)))` or 

how did you use the mutate function please

Comment: see, after applying a model, map will return a list. You just need one cell to store it, instead of entire column of a data frame.

Comment: what do you want to do with the output?

Comment: I want to maintain the output as a dataframe, add the model as a new column, extract the estimates and then use them in my plots

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `mutate` with `map`, you'll need to also use `tidyr` for `nest`. You'll be using tibbles to store the output (or data frames with list-columns of data frames).

I used the functions from @Sathish's detailed answer (with some modifications).

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 

df <- data.frame(tiny = rep(letters[1:3], 20), 
                 block = rnorm(60), tray = runif(60, min=0.4, max=2),
                 indent = sample(0.5:2.0, 60, replace = TRUE))

lm_model <- function( data ) 
{
  return( lm( block ~ tray, data = data ) )
}

# Altered function to include title parameter with purrr::map2
plot_fun <- function( data, title )
{
  p <- ggplot( data = data, aes( x = tray, y = block ) ) +
    geom_point( ) +
    xlab("Soil Properties") + 
    ylab("Slope Coefficient") +
    ggtitle( as.character( title ) )

  return( p )
}


results <- df %>% 
  group_by(tiny) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, lm_model),
         plot = map2(data, tiny, plot_fun))
```

You end up with:

```
> results

# A tibble: 3 × 4
    tiny              data    model     plot
  <fctr>            <list>   <list>   <list>
1      a <tibble [20 × 3]> <S3: lm> <S3: gg>
2      b <tibble [20 × 3]> <S3: lm> <S3: gg>
3      c <tibble [20 × 3]> <S3: lm> <S3: gg>
```

And you can access what you need using `unnest` or via extraction (`[` and `[[`)

```
> results$model[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = block ~ tray, data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         tray  
    -0.3461       0.3998
```

Comment: I have now been able to add the title to my plots. Thanks